# Test in a C++ static library project with NetBeans

Tags: c++, unit-testing, netbeans, static

I'm writing a static library in C++ with NetBeans (6.9.1). 
I compiled the project main source files with no errors but I don't know how to add a test to it.

I chose File -> New -> C/C++ Tests -> C++ Simple Test and added the static library and the include directory to its properties but when I try to compile the test, I get the following error:

make: *** No rule to make target

Is it because the test file has to be defined in a new project outside of the library project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to get around this one for a while. Apparently it's a bug, due to be fixed by Netbeans 7.0. http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=188854